# Call logger from multiple modules in Flask app

Tags: python, logging, flask

This is how my `app` is currently set up:

**Directory**

```
/xampp/code/menumaster
    menumaster
        __init__.py
        views.py
        sqltables.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
import menumaster.views
```

**views.py**

```
from menumaster import app, DBSession
@app.route('/restaurants', methods = ['GET'])
def getRestaurants():
    # Code here...
```

I'm wondering where and how I should be configuring the `logger` such that I would be able to use it in different modules and write to some file `mylog.txt`.

I have seen examples like this: https://gist.github.com/ibeex/3257877#file-foo-log

However, in my code I don't use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Should I add the `logger` configuration code in my `__init__.py` file and try it call from there? Any help with the proper way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

My code currently looks like this:

**views.py**

```
import logging
import logging.config

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %    (thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'error.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'WARN',
            'handlers': ['file'],
        },
    }
}   

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)    
logger = logging.getLogger('__name__')

@app.route('/restaurants', methods = ['GET'])
def getRestaurants():
    logger.debug('write something to log file') 
    return 'something'
```

I currently have two issues:

1) The text `"write something to log file"` is not appearing in `error.log`.

2) When I remove `setLevel(logging.INFO)` from `logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)`, nothing is written to `error.log`. I thought this would work as this information was already set in the `LOGGING` variable.

I tried changing both the `handler` and `logger` level to `INFO` in `LOGGING` but to no avail.

Comment: Does it work with `logger.error()`?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: Yes, when I use `logger.error()` the message appears.

Comment: I think the root log handler error level is not configured correctly. `'': {'level': 'INFO'}` should do the trick if your code is correct otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is that each Python module declares its own logger like this:

```
 import logging

 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then you can use the standard Python logging configuration to increase or decrease logging verbosity per module and redirect log output from different modules to different logging handlers / files.

[See configuring Python logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html).

Below is a simple logging configuration dict showing how to set up file logging:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },


    'handlers': {


        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/django.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },


    },

    'loggers': {}

        '': {
            'level': 'WARN',
            'handlers': ['file'],
        },

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Mikko. I am encountering a few issues which I have added to my question.